# Character/URI encoding in JavaScript getting out of sync?

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8

I have a question about encoding special/extended UTF-8 characters in URLs in JavaScript. The same question applies to many characters like the Registered R-circle, but my example uses an umlaut:

ü = %C3%BC in UTF-8 (four rows from bottom of http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

If the url contains an umlaut represented as UTF-8 (ü = %C3%BC), and I run it through encodeURIComponent, the %s are encode, the string now looks like "%25C3%25BC" and it gets correctly processed by my system. This is good.

url = "http://foo.com/bar.html?%C3%BC"
url = encodeURIComponent(url);
// url is now represented as "http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com%2Fbar.html%3F%25C3%25BC"

However, the bad: If the pre-encoded string has an unencoded character, the actual umlaut, the after encoding is looks like "%C3%BC" and fails because, I believe, the %s should be encoded, too.:

url = "[http://foo.com/bar.html?ü](http://foo.com/bar.html?%C3%BC)"
url = encodeURIComponent(url);
// url is now represented as "http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com%2Fbar.html%3F%C3%BC"

I think it fails because it is less thoroughly encoded than the rest of the url.

So, beyond general advice or answers to questions I don't know to ask, what I think i want to know is how to get the raw umlaut (and all other special characters) to fully encode. Is that what is incorrect?

Thanks for your help!
Nate

Comment: You're double encoding. What kind of system are you using that expects that?

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* encode a URL all at once.  If you have already concatenated the host, path, parameters, etc., together then it's impossible to correctly determine which characters actually need to be encoded and which characters are separators that need to be left alone.

The only reliable way to build a URL is by concatenating already-encoded values:

```
"http://foo.com/bar.html?" + encodeURIComponent("%C3%BC")
```